# Desabilitar Radio Button para usuários

Tags: javascript

Por favor gostaria de uma ajuda e se tem como fazer o que vou relatar aqui.

Linguagem JavaScript.

O usuário entra com uma determinada data, o sistema já muda o radio button para a opção 1, dependendo da data ele muda para a opção 2, mas não quero que o usuário tenha autonomia para selecionar, apenas o sistema deve fazer essa mudança.

Eu teste o `disabled = true;` Mas este não funcionou como que queria, Ele desabilitou todo radio button.

Tentei também fazer uma função no script, mas não deu certo.

Tem como fazer isso?

Comment: *"Tem como fazer isso?"* Provavelmente deve ter, agora nos resta saber a linguagem a qual a pergunta se refere pois foram marcadas três linguagens nas tags. Por favor leia [ask], veja o que é um [mcve] e visite nossa [help].

Answer (score -4, accepted):

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="opcao" id="opcao1" value="1"> Opção 1<br>
    <input type="radio" name="opcao" id="opcao2" value="2"> Opção 2<br>
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
// Supondo que você já tenha obtido a data do usuário e armazenado em uma variável chamada dataUsuario
var dataUsuario = new Date('2024-03-18');

// Supondo que a data limite para mudar para a opção 2 seja 2024-03-20
var dataLimite = new Date('2024-03-20');

// Verifique se a data do usuário é posterior à data limite
if (dataUsuario > dataLimite) {
    // Se for, desabilite o botão de rádio da opção 1
    document.getElementById("opcao1").disabled = true;
} else {
    // Caso contrário, desabilite o botão de rádio da opção 2
    document.getElementById("opcao2").disabled = true;
}
```

Neste exemplo, você precisa adaptar a lógica de verificação da data do usuário e a data limite conforme necessário para o seu caso específico. Você também precisará executar este código depois que a página for carregada, idealmente dentro de um evento DOMContentLoaded ou no final do corpo do documento.